# Any thing wrong with this xml layout file? Why setContentView fails after loading this file and the app closed after this

Tags: xml, android-layout

Here's the XML file. Strange that my program exited right away after executing setContentView. The logcat showed nothing but this

> thread id=1 thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417d)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">


  <TextView android:id="@+id/SpeechResult"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edge"
    android:padding="6dip"
    android:hint="Waht is on your mind?"/>

  <ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/ToggleRecognition"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:textOff="Start"
    android:textOn="Stop"
    android:onClick="onToggleRecognition"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the tweak, it's really confusing and I think eclipse should at least have some debugging info 'cause this is really catchy. The problem has been related to the missing layout_width attribute in TextView. Not sure why this would lead to a crash, but at least adding it made the maggice